# Change day of DateTime object using values in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Say I have a data frame of 10,000+ rows with columns `Day` and `Month` where `Month` is a datetime object. The value for "day" in the `Month` object is incorrect so I want to replace it with the corresponding value from the `Day` column. How would I go about doing that?

```
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({
'Month': [dt.date(2017,9,1),dt.date(2017,11,1),dt.date(2017,9,1)],
'Day': [7, 21,14],
})

Day Month
7   2017-09-01
21  2017-11-01
14  2017-09-01
```

So I want the end result to look like this:

```
Day Month       New_Col
7   2017-09-01  2017-09-07
21  2017-11-01  2017-11-21
14  2017-09-01  2017-09-14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert column `Month` to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and add column `Day` converted [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html)s:

```
df['New_Col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Day'], unit='d')
print (df)
        Month  Day    New_Col
0  2017-09-01    7 2017-09-08
1  2017-11-01   21 2017-11-22
2  2017-09-01   14 2017-09-15
```

If need subtract one day:

```
df['New_Col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Day'] - 1, unit='d')
print (df)
        Month  Day    New_Col
0  2017-09-01    7 2017-09-07
1  2017-11-01   21 2017-11-21
2  2017-09-01   14 2017-09-14
```

Comment: perhaps you can check another question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54609989/how-to-calculate-mean-and-variance-from-pandas-datetime-object?noredirect=1#comment96014861_54609989.

Comment: @JAG2024 Sorry, I am offline now, on phone only.

Comment: That's okay! Thanks.