# How to calculate mean and variance from pandas datetime object?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, summary

How do I calculate summary statistics (mean and standard deviation) for python datetime objects in the form YYYY-MM-DD? I want to do this for different groups of datetime obejcts which have different IDs.

Here's what the data look like:

```
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({
'Date': [dt.date(2017,9,1),dt.date(2017,9,21),dt.date(2017,9,14),
    dt.date(2017,11,7),dt.date(2017,8,1),dt.date(2017,12,21),
    dt.date(2017,12,14),dt.date(2017,10,1),dt.date(2017,10,1)],
'ID': [1,2,3,3,2,1,2,3,2],
})

    Date        ID
    2017-09-01  1
    2017-11-01  2
    2017-09-01  3
    2017-11-07  3
    2017-08-01  2
    2017-11-01  1
    2017-12-01  2
    2017-10-01  3
    2017-10-01  2
```

And I want a result that looks like:

```
ID_1_mean  ID_1_sd  ID_2_mean   ID_2_sd ...
YYYY-MM-DD int      YYYY-MM-DD  int ...
```

where YYYY-MM-DD is the mean from the dates in group 1 and int is the mean in group 1, repeated for all the groups.

Comment: lookup pandas groupby

Comment: @anishtain4 yes but then how do you take the mean of datetime objects?

Comment: datetime are numbers, or you can just change them to numbers as the submitted answer shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a somewhat clunky workaround:

1. Convert `datetime.date` to `pandas.Timestamp` with `pd.to_datetime()`
2. Convert `pandas.Timestamp` to integer with `.astype(int)`
3. Compute mean and std of these integers
4. Convert mean to `pandas.Timestamp`
5. Convert std to `pandas.Timedelta`

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Date': [dt.date(2017,9,1),dt.date(2017,9,21),dt.date(2017,9,14),
    dt.date(2017,11,7),dt.date(2017,8,1),dt.date(2017,12,21),
    dt.date(2017,12,14),dt.date(2017,10,1),dt.date(2017,10,1)],
'ID': [1,2,3,3,2,1,2,3,2],
})
```

Solution:

```
df['Date_int'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).astype(int)
res = df.groupby('ID').agg(['mean', 'std'])
res.columns = ['_'.join(c) for c in res.columns.values]

res['Date_mean'] = pd.to_datetime(res['Date_int_mean'])
res['Date_std'] = pd.to_timedelta(res['Date_int_std'])

res = res[['Date_mean', 'Date_std']]
res

             Date_mean                Date_std
ID                                            
1  2017-10-26 12:00:00 78 days 11:43:56.874291
2  2017-10-01 18:00:00 55 days 15:53:10.401720
3  2017-10-07 16:00:00 27 days 14:38:57.222514
```